# Rails/Postgres nested JSON query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a JSON column in my `events` table called `payload`. I can create an event like this:

```
Event.create!(application_id: 1, stage: 'INITIATION', payload: { key: 'OUTCOME', value: {school_id: 2, prefered_language: 'GBP'}})
```

Simple queries like

```
Event.where("payload->>'key' = ?", "OUTCOME")
```

Will work fine, but how can I then add extra filters with the JSON that's nested in the `value` portion

```
 Event.where("payload->>'key' = ? AND payload ->>'value'->>'school' = ?", "OUTCOME", 2) 
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried that but i got:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
LINE 1: ...ad ->>'key' = 'INPUTPARAMS' AND payload ->>'value'->>'school...                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How do I get into the school attribute within value?

I have taken the idea from this [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) on ActiveRecord and JSON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much searching, I came across this [article](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

The `#>>` operator allows you to dig inside the JSON. My query could be fixed like this.

```
Event.where("payload->>'key'= ? AND payload#>>'{value, school_id}' = ?", 'OUTCOME', shcool_id)
```

You could theoretically go down further by adding each layer to the predicate block `{value, school, next_level, and_so_on}`